# Caching various statistics in a special one row table?

Tags: postgresql, caching

Expecting hundreds of millions of rows and write-heavy applciation.

We need return `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders` and `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM orders` quite frequently and both of them are too slow to be ran on every request.

We are thinking about adding a special table called `stats` with just a single row. It has `total_orders` and `total_amount`, which we would increase every time we add a new order. Is this kind of SQL "cache" table a practical solution? What does it mean in terms of write performance?

Another option is to use Memcached or Redis, but they can get out of sync and are not persistent. Any other ideas?